# Handling dynamic web element in robot and clicking on their correspondence value

Tags: robotframework

I have a web table, and within it there is a row name which is dynamic. The value is entered by a user. Suppose that the text "Test" is located on the 8th row; if someone enters some value again, a different value will be in "Test"'s location, and "Test" will be in a different location within the table. I want to specifically click on "Test".

How can I click the action of "Test" when the location is being changed through user input?

Comment: Have you read up on how to use xpath? You can specify the nth child of an element.

Comment: You need to give us more information about the scenario to get better answers.  It sounds to me like the row position is actually changing, not just the id/name?  If so as @BryanOakley has suggested XPath can be used, perhaps you need to use contains() if you need to find specific text

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,thats correct need to use contains.
I got the answer and it is : "//span[contains(text(),'')]/../following-sibling::*//div[@id='']"